# Prevent all views redraw

Tags: android, canvas, android-framelayout

I have an FrameLayout which contains many child view. Each child view implements the `onDraw()` method to draw some shapes it maintains. Whenever I change something on a child view, I see that all other child-views will be invoked to re-draw itself. This makes the application runs slowly. Is there any way to re-draw only current child-view?

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. Did you find a solution?